# How to calculate irregularities in a surface in python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to calculate how irregular the surface is for various images. I attach one of the images below:

[image]

The idea would be to calculate the direction vectors every few samples and see how similar they are to each other (with the scalar product for example), if they are very similar it means that the surface is quite regular and the scalar product will be close to 1. If the irregularity is huge, it will be close to 0. Something like this:

[image]

I would be grateful for any help. Thank you!!!

Comment: Well, `cv2.findContours()` gets you an ordered list of points...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first part of a solution for you – computing the "roughness" is up to you...

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read, convert, threshold image
im = cv.imread('5FH31.png')
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)

# Find the outermost contour
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Decimate the contour to an approximation, squeeze to get an N x 2 array
dec_points = np.squeeze(cv.approxPolyDP(np.squeeze(contours), 3, True))

# Compute vectors from point + follower
vecs = dec_points - np.roll(dec_points, 1, 0)

# TODO: compute "roughness"? :)

# Debug: show our image and data
plt.imshow(im)
xs, ys = zip(*dec_points)
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'y')
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'r+')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The debug image will look something like this - you can see each point and the contour they form.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Is there a way to calculate the points in a constant way? thanks again:)

Comment: What do you mean "in a constant way"?

Comment: I mean that every, for example, 50 points along the contour line you get one point.
Is this possible?

Comment: Well, you can change how `dec_points` is computed – the function I use, [`approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c) allows setting the distance between points in the approximation.